# send yes/no during shell command executing from python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

Could you help me how to send y/n during shell command execution.

below is example code:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["zypper", "install", "cifs-utils"])
```

During execution command It will ask below

```
 ****someting*****
 continue? [y/n? shows all options ](y):
```

from python script now i need to pass "y"

I tried   print "y\n" but it does not help

OS is linux (SuSE) and Python version is 2.7

Comment: You probably want `zypper --non-interactive` to not be prompted anywhere. See the zypper man pages for more info.

Comment: Please mention, what OS are you using?

Comment: Use the `Popen` class instances of `subprocess` directly, in particular the [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method.

Comment: Thanks for Popen, It solves my problem and edited my quetion

Answer (score 0):

As per Evert comment I have achieved with below code

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 
cmd = "zypper install cifs-utils"
execute = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
execute.stdin.write("y")
```